# How Can I add text on the top of image like pulse in android

Tags: user-interface, android-layout, android

I want to recreate pulse like UI for one of my android app. I want to know How can I put transparent text over an image like pulse also how can I create 2nd screen like pulse where we read the stories. In this screen How this bottom selecting elements comes and hide automatically and when clicked is it the complete activity being changed or only the text changes?.

Find below the two UI which I am mentioning about

[image]

How this bottom navigation is hiding?

[image]

Thanks pranay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `RelativeLayout`.
Here is an example which places a TextView on Top of an ImageView and centers the text on the image.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MyImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextOnImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks that solve 1 part what about the infinite scroll which comes down and how to hide that bottom scroll navigation when some body clicks on the top?

Comment: So i figure out how to hide the bottom scroll it is a sliding drawer http://www.androidpeople.com/android-sliding-drawer-tutorial now just want to figure out how the infinite scrolling is working and how can i change the content when somebody clicks on any of the photos

Comment: Infinite scrolling? Are you talking about Gallery?

Comment: is it gallery at the bottom or a horizontal listview? where news are coming in 1st screenshot

Answer (score 1):

A relativeLayout will solve your problem, because it allows you to define the position of every child element independantly from each other. Just use margin and paddings to adjust the exact layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Relative layout